# how to change a page by putting URL directly on this website

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to change a page by putting URL directly on this website

http://www.gojane.com/shop-by-category-shoes-heels.html

go to that webpage.

If I want to change the page 2, What values do I have to put URL directly?

like what page=2 or something.

I analyzed it for long time, but they used jquery.

Kind of difficult to find out.

Anyone know how to do it?

Please help me out, I'm so serious.

Comment: `window.location.href` ?

Comment: are you referring to pagination ?

Comment: you mean URL Redirect?

Comment: If I understood your correctly you are refering to pagination

Comment: I mean I do put URL address directly to change the page

Comment: http://www.gojane.com/shop-by-category-shoes-heels.html?page=2 like that way does not work.

Comment: in case of 6pm.com http://www.6pm.com/women-clothing-page/p=3 I found out that p is the page variable value. p=[page]

Comment: But, in case of gojane.com, I could not find out what value controls the page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 $('document').ready(function(){
 window.location.href='your url';
 });
<script>
```

Comment: I want to know not scipt sourse, but URL address to change the page.